# Updating Array Value in json

Tags: python

I have a json file that has information as such:

```
{
     "bank_details": [
        {
            "669349997011140614": {
                "wallet": 5,
                "bank": 10
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the json to reflect changes within the array, for example I want to add money to the wallet. How would I do that without messing up the rest of the json file?

This is how i'm currently changing the amount:

Method to access data:

```
async def get_bank_data():
  with open("bank.json","r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)['bank_details']
  return users
```

Actual code to try and change wallet amount:

```
  users = await get_bank_data()
  earnings = int(amt)

  
  for i in users:
    vals = i.keys()
    for x in vals:
      if x == str(author.id):
        wallet_amt = i[x]["wallet"]
        wallet_amt += earnings
        print(wallet_amt)
        i[x]["wallet"]=wallet_amt
```

Comment: The easiest way is to write the updated JSON object of type `dict` to the file with `json.dump` method.

Comment: Where do you access `bank_details` in the code?

Comment: There are no arrays in your example, only list(s) and dictionaries.

Comment: @DYZ JSON arrays correspond to Python lists.

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Comment: Load the entire JSON file into a Python variable. Update just the part you want to change, then dump the entire variable back to the file.

Comment: BTW, it's generally easier to use `for key, value in dictionary.items():`

Comment: How would I load the entire JSON file into a variable, can you please show me an example?

Comment: Edit: I was able to load it into a variable but when I try to update it and print it out there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key_for_user in users.keys():
    for wallet_key in users[key_for_user][0].keys():
        users[key_for_user][0][wallet_key]["wallet"]=users[key_for_user][0][wallet_key]["wallet"]+earnings
```

Step 1: Get the first key of the json file. ("bank_details")

Step 2: you will get a list from json with this key.

Step 3: access the jsons in this list you have obtained

Step 4: Access the wallet via the primary IDs in these jsons

step 5: update the wallet value